Saving value as JToken gives an empty array
I have this code:
...
JToken assignmentToken;

if (property.Value.Type == JTokenType.Object || property.Value.Type == JTokenType.Array)
{
    // Directly assign the JToken for complex types
    assignmentToken = property.Value;
}
else
{
    // Convert simple types to strings then to JToken
    string valueAsString = property.Value.ToString();
    assignmentToken = JToken.FromObject(valueAsString);
}

propertiesAssignments.Assignments[property.Key] = assignmentToken;

propertiesAssignments.AssignmentConfigurations[property.Key] = new AssignmentConfiguration
{
    PropertyType = new PropertyType(PropertyDataType.String, PropertyAssignmentType.Literal),
    Label = property.Key,
    Editor = new PropertyEditor(ControlType.Label),
    AlternateEditor = null,
    IsRequired = false,
    IsReadOnly = true,
    Placeholder = property.Value.ToString()
};
...

and I'm doing this inside a foreach for multiple properties, the case I'm testing is this list of properties:
{"property1":"activity","property2":2,"nestedProperty":{"nestedKey":"nestedValue"}}
and on the Placeholder I get the values correctly, for example: placeholder": "{\r\n  \"nestedKey\": \"nestedValue\"\r\n}" but on the assignments I get an empty array for all the values, like:
"assignments": {
                "property1": [],
                "property2": [],
                "nestedProperty": [
                    [
                        []
                    ]
                ]
            },

and I just can't figure out why. The property is of type: KeyValuePair<string,JToken> and the assignments is a Dictionary<string,JToken>. Any suggestions please?
I tried assigning the value directly to the assignments, convert it to string and parsing the value back to a JToken and nothing
